# Cannot convert shapefile data to PostgreSQL/PostGIS using ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ogr2ogr

I am a starter to use command-line interface. I was looking for a way to import a shapefile into PostgreSQL using "**ogr2ogr**". I was able to do this for point shapefile using code:

```
ogr2ogr -f "POSTGRESQL" PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=postgres password=12345" "C:\Users\itsaa\Desktop\GIS DATA\WGS\sett.shp"
```

But using the same code for Multipolygon feature gave me an error message
[image: Error]

How can I get through this?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the tool?

Comment: That error is about the file. Does it exist? Is it a valid shapefile?

Comment: Test with ogrinfo: `ogrinfo "C:\Users\itsaa\Desktop\GIS DATA\WGS\your_polygon_shape.shp"`. Does it find your shapefile? I would not recommend to use spaces in the names of files and directories but with double quotes they should work. Also "Desctop" may not be the best choice for data, try something like C:\Users\itsaa\data instead, or just c:\data.

Comment: please don't use screenshots to display errors, it is very easy to cut and paste from a windows command window.

Comment: you can also try to use the QGIS DB Manager to insert your Shapefile into Postgres.

Comment: It is unwise to use the `postgres` user for anything but creating the logins, schemas, and roles necessary to the actual data loading.

Comment: @user30184 Thank You. The shapefile seemed to have some problem. It worked with other files.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use the PostGIS tool to load the shapefile. Please check the following link:

https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/loading_data.html

Comment: Using PostGIS I was able to do so. I want to use ogr2ogr code for the purpose.

Comment: find [here](https://jakobmiksch.eu/post/gdal_ogr/#postgis) some example how to use `ogr2ogr` with PostGIS

Comment: I cannot find the solution to my problem in the mentionedd page